# The #Deleted error saga continues with Access f/e and MySQL b/e

Tags: ms-access

First time caller, long time listener.  I'm using an Access f/e with a MySQL remote b/e.  There are a few threads on here about the #Deleted issues and BIGINT.  I'm not using BIGINT and the #Deleted errors are occuring for only the first 10 records of simple queries.  Pressing the F5 key updates the query and the errors go away.  Is this the same issue that has plagued Access/MySQL for years?  Why would only the first ten records error out? Is this a "timing" thing between MySQL and Access?  How do I work with this or work around it?

Here are a couple of screen shots. One of the query results with errors and the second is of the table structure. https://www.withallthymind.com/Access/Access_error_01.htm

Comment: Please post, Access version, MySQL server version, ODBC connector version. There are some issues with certain ODBC connectors

Comment: When you flip the Access linked table into design mode, does it see the table types correct and see the PK column?

Comment: I would replace the int(11) with just int. The 11 does not actually change the number that you can store in that column. It only pads to the left of the number. So int(4) does not mean 4 digits is the limit, but only up to 3 zeros in front can be padded if you have zero padding turned on. So, int or int(11) means the exact same thing. I would open up the Access table in design mode and see what access used and assumed for the column types.

Comment: Krish and Albert, thanks for your responses.  Find below the versions of what I am using.  Albert, Thanks for the precise guidance.  I will check my tables against your advice ASAP and let you know how it works out.

MySQL version:  5.6.41-84.1

MS Access Version:  Office 365

ODBC Connector Version:  10.0.18362.1

MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver:  8.00.18.00

Comment: Looking at your screen cap, you do have a PK,and you do have a timestamp. And you do have a default for the bit column. So, all 3 of my suggests look ok. What I would check is opening the client side linked table in design mode to ensure that access sees the columns as correct. If access sees the int columns as text, then try int as opposed to int(11) and re-link.

Comment: Thanks Albert.  I checked the Access table in Design View.  All looks good to me.  I added a screen shot to the link . . . https://www.withallthymind.com/Access/Access_error_01.htm

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this has to do with floating point rounding errors. (I bet you have a decimal or some type of column that is a number column. For any type of "money", then I STRONG recommend you use the "money" type column in place of a floating point column. (I don't know what MySQL offers).

However, to fix your issue, just ensure the following:

All tables have a PK key assigned. (I think you have this, but make sure).

All tables should have a timestamp column. Now in SQL server this is NOT a datetime column, but I think in MySQL, it is.
So this should work:

```
DummyTS timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW() ON UPDATE NOW()
```

Next up:
Bit or yes/no columns. DO NOT allow them to be null, and MAKE SURE they have a default of 0.

Make the above changes. You now have to re-link the access tables.

In most cases, null bits cause a issue. Lack of PK column. And adding a time stamp column also helps (access uses this column to determine if the record been changed. If it does NOT have this column, then Access resorts to a column by column. And if the table has any floating point numbers, then due to rounding errors, then it thinks the row of data has changed - and it messes things up. As noted, if you have floating numbers, if you can use "money" type column for that data, then you find this also tends to fix this issue.

> > why only first 10 records?

Likely null bit (yes/no) columns, or they have some floating point numbers that were NOT originally entered by Access, so there are rounding errors occurring, and access thinks the row has changed when it attempts to render.